# Sencha ExtJS How to have two buttons & text on same line

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

Along with the below code, two buttons and text go on top of each other, I need text to go to next to the bottom of the buttons. How can I achieve that?

[image]

```
  items: [{
            region: 'south',
            xtype: 'container',
            items: [{}],
            }, {
                xtype: 'container',
                html: 'sadfaasvdsavdassdf<br>saavsdsavdfasdfas'
            }]
    }],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below works, the key is using columnwidth, when they were set to 0.5 each, it didn't fit so I made them 0.49

```
}, {
        region: 'south',
        xtype: 'container',
        layout: 'column',
        items: [{
            height: 50,
            xtype: 'container',
            columnWidth: 0.49,
        }, {
            xtype: 'container',
            columnWidth: 0.49,
        }]
}],
```